# Read.csv is not Counting NAs in my Data Set

Tags: r, na, read.csv

First post on SO ever so I'm looking forward to getting some feedback from some veterans in R on the forum. :)

I have a [CSV file (2.52KB)](https://github.com/john-t-young/Inherent-Org-Hierarchy-Analysis/blob/master/DF_Cleanup_isNAError_Test.csv) that I'm currently unable to identify NAs when I run the following NA identifying script (particularly in ORG column):

```
 mydata = read.csv("DF_Cleanup_isNAError_Test.csv" header = TRUE, sep = ",", quote = "", dec = ".", fill = TRUE)
 nan_count <-sapply(mydata, function(y) sum(length(which(is.na(y)))))
 nan_count <- data.frame(nan_count)
 nan_count
```

When I isolate the records with NA values in ORG column though (only 30 total rows) in the [control data set](https://github.com/john-t-young/Inherent-Org-Hierarchy-Analysis/blob/master/DF_Cleanup_isNAError_Control.csv), running the same NA identifying script returns a count of 30 for column ORG.  This is expected for the script above as well but that's not happening.

```
mydata = read.csv("DF_Cleanup_isNAError_Control.csv" header = TRUE, sep = ",", quote = "", dec = ".", fill = TRUE)
nan_count <-sapply(mydata, function(y) sum(length(which(is.na(y)))))
nan_count <- data.frame(nan_count)
nan_count
```

I'm completely stumped right now on why there would be a difference with the addition of other records in the data set when nothing's changed about the individual records in question.  The test data set is still only a subset of the total population data; I have about 850K total rows but I figured this is a good start to isolating what the issue is.

Here's my current session info

```
    R version 3.4.1 (2017-06-30)
    Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
    Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

   Matrix products: default

   locale:
   [1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United 
   States.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
   [4] LC_NUMERIC=C                           LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

   attached base packages:
   [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

   other attached packages:
   [1] dplyr_0.7.2

   loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
    [1] compiler_3.4.1   magrittr_1.5     assertthat_0.2.0 R6_2.2.2         
    tools_3.4.1      bindrcpp_0.2     glue_1.1.1       tibble_1.3.3    
     [9] Rcpp_0.12.12     pkgconfig_2.0.1  rlang_0.1.1      bindr_0.1
```

Comment: It could be it's being read as `"NA"`. Could you try `which(y=="NA")` (in the context of your code) to test this?

Comment: Try adding `na.strings = ""` to your `read.csv` call.

Comment: side issue: your `sapply` can be replaced by `colSums(is.na(myData)`

Comment: @ChiPak Yep, I tested that before; it doesn't find anything in `DF_Cleanup_isNAError_Test.csv` and I've checked the CSV file as well.  Its not a 'NA' string but an actual blank value that the code isn't picking up for some reason between the test and control data sets.

Comment: That does it! It shows up with count = 30 for both control and test data sets.  Thanks @jav

Answer (score 2):

@jav answered this in the comments section but I figured this should actually be listed out as an answer.  If he ever reposts his comment as an answer, I'll delete this.

Adding `na.strings = ""` to `read.csv("filename.csv")` solves the problem.